# Multithread in ios plugin for Unity

Tags: ios, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am writing an iOS plugin for Unity. On Unity I will call a function in this iOS plugin.
I would like to know that: is this function will be run on main thread or background? Because it seems that this function will be run on background.
 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multithreaded Script invocation in Unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852174/multithreaded-script-invocation-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Unity everything runs on one thread. Unity is not multithreaded in any way.  (If you do launch a thread, you must "get back to" the main thread, to do anything in Unity, eg UI.) In your iOS level plugin, if you go to another thread that is "your problem". It won't go to another thread unless you specifically do that.  And then, you must entirely look after it.